# How to filter out my criteria by using WHERE NOT

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery and I was trying to look for a script to exclude some words in the table.

Below is my current script:

```
FROM `XXXX` A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNTRY_CODE, COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION 
FROM `XXXX` GROUP BY 1,2) B
ON A.COUNTRY = B.COUNTRY_CODE
LEFT JOIN `XXXX` C
ON A.SA_DATE = C.CALENDAR_DATE_STR 
WHERE PMD_PRODUCT_STATUS = 'Active'
AND (MILESTONE = 'Actual' or MILESTONE LIKE '%M0')
AND LOCKED IS false
```

I would like to change line `AND (MILESTONE = 'Actual' or MILESTONE LIKE '%M0')` instead of `MILESTONE = 'Actual'` & `'%M0'`. I would like it to exclude `MILESTONE = 'Exit'` and `MILESTONE = '%M0'`

For example

```
AND WHERE NOT (MILESTONE = 'Exit' or MILESTONE LIKE '%M0')
```

Right now Google BigQuery says

> Syntax error: Unexpected keyword WHERE at [61:7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there - just used extra WHERE so remove it as in below example

```
FROM `XXXX` A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNTRY_CODE, COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION 
FROM `XXXX` GROUP BY 1,2) B
ON A.COUNTRY = B.COUNTRY_CODE
LEFT JOIN `XXXX` C
ON A.SA_DATE = C.CALENDAR_DATE_STR 
WHERE PMD_PRODUCT_STATUS = 'Active'
AND NOT (MILESTONE = 'Exit' or MILESTONE LIKE '%M0')
AND LOCKED IS false
```